# clojure REPL doesn't pick up changes made to defrecord

Tags: clojure, record, read-eval-print-loop, slime, leiningen

I have a leiningen project set up.  In one of the clojure source files I've defined some records.  My workflow is to usually start emacs and connect to a 'lein swank' REPL.  Once I've connected to the REPL I switch into the appropriate namespace and C-c C-k a file, so I can start working with the REPL and the code in the file.  However, if I make changes to the records in that file and C-c C-k it, the REPL doesn't pick up the changes.

So, as it stands, every time I need to make changes to a record, I have to stop the lein swank process, restart it, and reconnect to it from emacs.  This is getting old very fast.  What am I missing?  I've tried C-c C-l instead of C-c C-k, but that doesn't work.  I've tried deleting the 'class' dir in the project root, but that's also a no-go.

I'd appreciate any insights or recommendations.

Also, as an aside, I'm always working in the namespace where the records are defined.

Edit: I'm actually changing the implementation of a protocol in the defrecord.  Once I change it and compile using C-c C-k, and create a new record in the REPL, the REPL is still using the old protocol implementation.

Comment: could you paste in a snippet from the repl showing the old value, changing it and then the new value. I think it would help add context so we can help more

Comment: @Arthur: I should have made this more clear.  I'm changing the implementation of a protocol in the defrecord, and when I make that change, the REPL is still using the old implementation - even after creating a new instance of the record.

Comment: I know Slime/Swank only from Common Lisp.  I am surprised that you do not use `C-c C-c` to compile individual toplevel forms.  By the way, there is `C-c ~` to switch package and directory of the REPL to the current file and point.

Comment: Could you paste in a chunk from the repl and the before and after snippets of the protocol definitions. If you're not in a position to be disclosing source perhaps you could make a contrived example with the same problem? ps: what version of clojure

Answer (score 4):

I could use an example, but perhaps you are changing the deffinition of the records and looking at instances of some records that where made before the change?

if you define an instance of the record from the repl, then change the defrecord, reload the repl, and then make a new one with a different name can you see both copies and the differences between them.

I try to avoid this kind of confusion by having a file in my project that calls `(use :reload-all ... all the namespaces in my project ...)` then i can reload just this file and the reload-all throws out the old var bindings etc.